# how can bind datalist with sqldatasource on page load in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using sqldatasouce as DataSourceID for datalist . but , its not allowing me to give an id  for datalist . how can i bind the datalist on page load .?I am getting following error Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DTest'. Remove one definition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working only with sqlDataSource, try binding your datalist with some IEnumerable that you would have prepared in your codebehind. It will allow you to customize things the way you want without losing too much time at understanding how things are done with ready made tool from microsoft which at best are working for simple cases.